# password protect pdf files created using pisa

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I'm converting a html file into pdf using python pisa module. I need to password protect it. I searched everywhere in pisa module and couldn't find a solution for it. Is there anyway to password protect it using python?

The constraint is I want keep my file in html format. On demand basis, I want to convert it into pdf file and password protect it. I don't want to use reportlab module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can with [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) which is optional for pisa but has an encryption method:

> A Pure-Python library built as a PDF toolkit. It is capable of:
>
> extracting document information (title, author, ...), splitting
>   documents page by page, merging documents page by page, cropping
>   pages, merging multiple pages into a single page, **encrypting and
>   decrypting PDF files**.

Comment: what you mean by pypdf is optional for pisa? is it capable of generating pdf using pisa and password protect it?

Answer (score 0):

you could make use of `encrypt` argument of `pisa.CreatePDF`

```
pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(html, encrypt='password', dest=response)
```